# What option is more correct?

Tags: grammar

What option is more correct? Eg: 1.It takes 5 minutes to download files. Or. 2. Downloading files takes 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Either is fine, but if you're talking about specific files, you need to use an article:

> It takes 5 minutes to download **the** files.

> Downloading **the** files takes 5 minutes.

If you don't use an article, you're making the statement about downloading files in general. It would work in a very specific context, but otherwise wouldn't. Some files take 5 minutes to download and others take 50 minutes.